# How to convert AsciiDoc to Perl POD?

Tags: perl, manpage, asciidoc, perl-pod

How to convert **manpage** written in ***[AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/)*** lightweight markup language automatically into Perl's ***[POD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html)*** (Plain Old Documentation)?

Perhaps something that converts from DocBook to POD (the conversion from AsciiDoc sources to manpage format i.e. troff goes via DocBook (via XML)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using `a2x` and `rman`, to first convert asciidoc to man page format, then to convert that to POD:

```sh
a2x -f manpage foo.1.txt
groff -e -mandoc -Tascii foo.1 | rman -f POD > foo.pod
```

The `groff` command is there to fix some formatting issues -- apparently `rman` does not understand specific macros produced by `a2x` (I found this piece of advice on this page: http://www.datastat.com/sysadminjournal/misctips.html).